# Group by 2 week period end on saturday

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have trolled around and see a lot of topic on grouping by week.  I need to group by 2 weeks ending on Saturday's.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2fea/1/0

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
         Total Numeric(9,2)
         created DATE
       );

INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('100','2009-01-01');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('50','2009-01-02');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('100','2009-01-03');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('50','2009-01-04');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('75','2009-01-05');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('150','2009-01-06');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('170','2009-01-07');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('111','2009-01-08');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('125','2009-01-09');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('151','2009-01-10');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('128','2009-01-11');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('175','2009-01-12');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('100','2009-01-13');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('50','2009-01-14');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('75','2009-01-15');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('150','2009-01-16');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('170','2009-01-17');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('111','2009-01-18');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('125','2009-01-19');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('151','2009-01-20');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('128','2009-01-21');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('175','2009-01-22');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('100','2009-01-23');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('50','2009-01-24');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('75','2009-01-25');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('150','2009-01-26');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('170','2009-01-27');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('111','2009-01-28');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('125','2009-01-29');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('151','2009-01-30');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('128','2009-01-31');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('111','2009-02-01');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('125','2009-02-02');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('151','2009-02-03');
INSERT INTO contacts (Total,created) VALUES('128','2009-02-04');
```

I know that 01/03/2009 is the Saturday I wish to start from.  I want to sum of the Totals and then group by the previous 2 weeks showing the ending date, if the ending Saturday has not passed yet show the total up to the current date  something like this.

```
Total   Date
250     1/3/2009
1680    1/17/2009
1750    1/31/2009
515     2/4/2009
```

This is just one month and the output would actually continue through current date.

Comment: are these your types?  varchar and date?

Comment: No I am sorry, missed that when I was creating the SQL fiddle table... it is actually numeric(9,2) and date is date.

Comment: and your SQL version is correct on fiddle?

Comment: Yes I update the question and the SQL fiddle table link.

Comment: this works in SQL 2000 where conversions where kindly:  `SELECT sum(total) as sum, cast(floor((created+NN)/14)) as date
FROM contacts
group by floor((created+NN)/14)` where `NN` is a constant in range 0 to 13. this do not work in current version even including some casts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a way to place every date into two-week clumps that ignores years. It would also be nice to know the date the two-week-or-less total is referenced from, like you show in your expected output.

```
SELECT  Max( c.Created ) as ReferenceDate, Sum( c.Total ) SampleTotal,
        count(*) as DaysInSample
FROM    contacts c
group by DatePart( wk, c.Created ) / 2;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2fea/12/0)</kbd>

When it is a clump that is entirely in the past, the `Max` returns the date of the leading Saturday. Otherwise, it gets the date of the most recent entry. I included a "Days per sampling period" indicator to easily identify full two-week samples.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for...some reason I was having a brain meltdown last Friday.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't give exactly the answer you're looking for, but it might help you find it:

```
SELECT sum(total), round(datepart(wk, created) / 2, 0)
    FROM contacts
    GROUP BY round(datepart(wk, created) / 2, 0)
```

Comment: `code`  SELECT sum(total)
, DateAdd(day, -1 * datepart(dw, created), created )
    FROM contacts
    GROUP BY DateAdd(day, -1 * datepart(dw, created), created )  `code`    This is a start but it groups by one week and by the start of the week.  I need it reversed and group by 2 week range.

Comment: My code does the two weeks, but doesn't allow you to tweak which day it's counting from. I'm sure there's a setting somewhere that allows that, but I don't know where it is at the momeent...

Comment: I see what you are saying but that will not work when you start adding in several years...  hmmm